# a light bulb is connected as in the circuit shown below.

Tags: probability-or-statistics, education, mathematica-online

[image]

Please explain answer detail. Thanks

Comment: By the way, did you notice that this is the site for the software *Mathematica*, and not the [site for math questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: Also not the site for "do my homework for me questions"...

Comment: Not a right forum But hint is: If both path are not work bulb not lit. First path will not work with probability $(2p-p^2)$ and second cant work is $p$. Multiply both u get probability both will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mathematica's [`Probability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html) functionality to check this:

```
Probability[And[p1 == 1, Or[p2 == 1, p3 == 1]], {
   p1 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p],
   p2 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p],
   p3 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p]}] // Simplify
```

Comment: The Option D is the answer .. can you please explain it ?